# group by with condition + UNION and JOIN

Tags: mysql, union

I just want to delete row `id =  819` with 0 in `expire_date` .. when I used  group by , system removed the row has `expire_date` but I don't remove theme I need them

My query result:

[image]

Here is my query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ads.id,  a.expire_date
FROM(SELECT id, expire_date from ads   
UNION  
SELECT ads_id as id , expire_date from ads_order where expire_date > NOW())
    a  JOIN  ads on ads.id = a.id  

    ORDER by a.expire_date DESC , ads.id DESC
```

Comment: why you need union and join? why not just `DELETE ... WHERE id = 819 and expire_date = '0'` ( i guess expire date is a string you should make it a date field)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
  
  And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

  [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

  Try create a sample in http://rextester.com